# Accessing a server on a different network than the primary network

Tags: networking, router, routing, subnet

I have a issue where I can't reach a server that is on a different network than the primary gateway. 
My network looks like this:

**Router 1** (192.168.1.1) ---> **Router 2** (192.168.1.129) --->  **Server** (172.16.1.30).

Router 1 (ASUS RT68U) is the first gateway in the network. Router 2 (ZYXEL USG 100) has a DHCP server with the network IP 172.16.1.1, which assigns the IP 172.16.1.30 to my server. Router 1 has DHCP and NAT enabled. Router 2 doesnt have NAT activated.

How can I access/create a route to the server on 172.16.1.30 from any computer that is only connected to the first gateway at 192.168.1.1?

Comment: How could your server even access the Internet when router 1 has no idea on how to reach it?

Comment: At which point did I state that I had Internet connection from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a static route on router 1 which will forward traffic destined for 172.16.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.129. How this is done depends on the specific router.

There is a guide for the specific Asus router [here](http://help.unotelly.com/support/solutions/articles/165803-setup-static-routes-on-asus-routers). In short:

- Log on
- Go to LAN
- Click on the Route tab
- Enter as network 172.16.1.0
- Enter as netmask 255.255.255.0
- Enter as gateway 192.168.1.129
- Enter as metric 2
- Enter as interface LAN or LAN & Wireless

Make sure the server has it's default route (gateway) set to router 2.

Comment: I did that. It did not work. I added 172.16.1.1 as destination and 192.168.1.129 (Router 2) as the gateway. When I ping the address to the server i get a request timeout as a reply.

Comment: I tested a static route like the following (didnt work):

Destination: 172.16.1.1 (Network ID on Router 2). Server is on this network.
Net Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.129 (WAN IP on Router 2)

Would a reboot of the Router 1 help? Could it be some policy or firewall rule causing this to fail? The thing is thought, I haven't added or modified any rules or policies on the Router 2.

Comment: Firewalls can mess up everything. It's best to disable them while testing (and reenable them afterwards). Can you see if traffic arrives at 192.168.1.129?